# The scroll bar appear even if set 100 width and height

Tags: html, css, height, width

I start to learn web development so I bought a course on udemy.For now I'm learning CSS3/HTML5 and a began a little project with CSS3.A web page which represent the Universe.I want to create an animation.
I have a problem: I want that the page to be full width and height ( no scrolling ).Firstly I put the black color on the page and after that I created a 616x616 png image with white dots which represent the stars.Well, after I place the stars on the page, full width/height dissappear and the scrolling is active.Why ?
This is my HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Earth Planet Orbiting</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="bower_components/html5shiv/dist/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body id="universe">
    <div id="stars"></div>
    <div id="sun"></div>
    <div id="earth0rbit">
        <img src="images/earth.png" alt="Earth" width="130" height="125">
        <div id="moon0rbit">
            <div id="moon"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is CSS code

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
#universe {
background: black;
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(#555, #000);
background: -moz-radial-gradient(#555, #000);
background: -o-radial-gradient(#555, #000);
background: radial-gradient(#555, #000);
}
#stars {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-image: url('images/stars.png');

}
```

If I delete from #stars the lines with width and height, the scroll is disabled but the dots (stars are't appearing)
What can I do ?
Sorry for my english!

Comment: you should add  overflow:auto;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, set the margins of `html` and `body` to 0. The default margin is 8px, so the total width of the body is 100% (of the window) plus 16px, totalling more than 100%!

Secondly, in your current example the #stars div is 100% high, but then you have some other content after it, 125px in all, which means the total content height is 100% plus 125px. The solution to that one is to decrease the height of #stars by 125px.

```css
html, body {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
margin:0; /* new */
}
#universe {
background: black;
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(#555, #000);
background: -moz-radial-gradient(#555, #000);
background: -o-radial-gradient(#555, #000);
background: radial-gradient(#555, #000);
}
#stars {
width: 100%;
height: calc(100% - 125px);
background-image: url('images/stars.png');

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Earth Planet Orbiting</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="bower_components/html5shiv/dist/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body id="universe">
    <div id="stars"></div>
    <div id="sun"></div>
    <div id="earth0rbit">
        <img src="images/earth.png" alt="Earth" width="130" height="125">
        <div id="moon0rbit">
            <div id="moon"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Or, more likely, I think you meant for the other divs to be inside the #stars div, right? In that case, move its end tag down.

Comment: Hi,thank you for your answer!Yes,it's working but I don;t understand the part with 125px.125px from where ?I'm noob..

Comment: In your example, the body contains three divs: #stars, #sun and #earth0rbit. The height of #stars is 100% (set in the stylesheet) and #earth0rbit is 125px (because of the 125 pixel high image in it). So if you want the total content to not exceed 100%, the height of #stars should be reduced to 100% - 125px to make room for the #earth0rbit below. Does that help?

Comment: (Of course it's perfectly possible for a page to be more than 100% high, but then you get the scrollbar.) Anyway, as I noted at the bottom of my answer, my guess is that you meant for the other two divs to be inside #stars, can that be right?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much.I understood perfectly.As I said I code this animation in the same time with the course;s author.The author wrote the code the same as I wrote.( the universe contains stars sun and earthorbit with moon.Sun and earthorbit aren't in #stars in the course.)The strange part is that with the code which I wrote the webpage works perfectly on his browser.Maybe the cause is the updates or a old version ?Anyway, thank you so much for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want no scrolling add this to your css

```
html,body{width:100%; height:100%;
overflow:hidden;}
```